# Wrong Character Encoding when exporting jasper as HTML stream

Tags: encoding, jasper-reports, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm using jasper library v. 6.2.2 with Oracle ADF 11, our servers are running Red Hat 6

I'm facing an issue with the special characters like French accent "€ è é ê û â"

when I export the report as a PDF everything works fine but on the same environment when exporting the report as HTML output using SimpleHtmlExporterOutput I get bad charachters  like this "Ã¨, Ã©..."

i tried changing the encoding to UTF8 and cp1252 when calling the class SimpleHtmlExporterOutput but still facing the same issue,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed the JAVA_OPTIONS on weblogic start params adding -Dfile.encoding=utf8 and forcing weblogic to start with UTF-8 and this solved my problem